# Adding JScrollPane to GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Everytime I click a button in my program, I add 5 new rows to the `JPanel`. Eventually, the rows overflow and I would like to add a JScrollPane so I can scroll down and see the new rows.

I know how to get it working for a `TextArea` but I can't seem to figure out how to make it work when I have a `GridBagLayout`. Below, I will attach the code for setting up my panels.

```
    JPanel panelMain = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(panelMain);

    JPanel panelForm = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    panelMain.add(panelForm);

    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(panelForm);
    panelMain.add(scrollpane);
```

When I run, my code I get a box enclosing the `GridBagLayout`, but the scrollpane is nowhere to be seen.

Comment: If you need more help then post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Maybe you aren't using GridBagLayout correctly since I don't see any constraints used anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
JPanel panelMain = new JPanel();
getContentPane().add(panelMain);
```

You would typically add the scroll pane directly to the frame. There is no need for the "panelMain".

```
panelMain.add(panelForm);
```

That line is not needed. A component can only belong to a single parent. You later add "panelForm" to the scrollpane.

So the basic code would be:

```
JPanel panelForm = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(panelForm);
frame.add(scrollpane);
```

> but the scrollpane is nowhere to be seen.

The scrollbars only appear when needed by default. Adding empty panels will not cause the scrollbar to be displayed. Click on your button a few times and add your child components to the "panelForm" using the appropriate GridBagConstraints. You will then need to use:

```
panelForm.revalidate();
panelForm.repaint();
```

The revalidate() causes the layout manager to be invoked so the scrollpane can determine is scrollbars are required or not.